# How to change image color by select

Tags: javascript, php

What is the best way to change image color?

[image]

I have this static image where every house is painted blue, in database the houses have x and y coordinates which make the red pointer. And now I want to made sold houses red. I know that I need to add new "sold" 1 or 0 on db but how should I change the color?

Comment: Your question lacks indication on how the map is generated. I hope it's not a static image ?

Comment: I prefer wax pastels myself. And seriously show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with SVG. Its ultra dynamic. You can easily change colors size... everything you need. Here is a simple live demo I found. http://typeof.it/archives/inline-svg-colors/index.html Its more flexible than static images.

An alternative is to create static images in each variant, but this can be an endless story.